# Open an appointment in Outlook on the Web

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, outlook-web-app

Is it possible to programmatically open Outlook Web UI to edit specific appointment (or any other entity) given that you have Exchange credentials? In other words, is it possible to have button on you website, by clicking which the Outlook on the web is opened with a specific appointment ready to be edited.

In case it's not possible, are there any alternatives, other than using EWS and creating your own UI.